# Windows 7 Power User on Domain cant do file shares

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing, windows-domain

At my organization we are running windows 7 and all of our users are power users and are not local admins on their machines. I am running into an issue were the Developers aren't able to create any file shares. Does anyone know a way for them to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group "Power Users" is obsolete since Vista and removed from the ACL. So don't use it any longer!

Comment: What kind of a group can I use to have my users have permissions similiar to a XP power user group then?

Comment: you have to decide if you want to add them to the admin group or add the to the users group with limited rights.

Comment: ok would that be in the local GPO or would I have to make a group? I also read something about making a new security template to have similar rights is that any help?

Comment: I don't know if there is a template. But as I said, add them to the normal users group.